# What is a classpath container?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, classpath, containers

I'm using Eclipse IDE and I don't really understand what a classpath container is. I know that it is declared in the .classpath file for example:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer"/>
```

If I remove this entry, then eclipse can't find any of the dependencies declared in `build.gradle`. How does this work? Can I create my own classpath containers? What do all the atrributes (`exported`, `kind`, `path`) mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"When in doubt, just read the javadocs."

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IClasspathContainer.html

So a classpath container is a class that tells the compiler where the dependencies for your project is.